# Why there is no find item to get a unique item in QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have unique QTreeWidgetItems in QTreeWidget, I am using findItems() to find a specific item, it returns list of items. From this list taking the first item and storing in QTreeWidgetItem. but i wonder is there any method to find an item which returns only one item,  if found ?

Comment: Why do you want that? finditems() gives you what you need.

Comment: instead of storing in a list and taking the first item, i want directly store it to a QTreeWidgetItem and use it

Comment: Umm, OK: `QTreeWidgetItem it = *myQTreeWidget -> finditems().at(0);`